# Facebook comment box- URL unreacable

Tags: facebook, comments

I've been using a blogger blog for 3 years. The original URL of the blog is- 'tariquldipu.blogspot.com'
I bought a custom URL for my blog in September'13 & its URL is- 'www.tariquldipu.net'

I'm using facebook comment box in my blog site for two years. It worked fine(even after i added the custom domain). But for last one week the comment box is showing- 'Warning URL is unreachable' suddenly. And also the comment box isn't accepting me as the admin of it and thus it is showing no settings/moderate butttons like it did before. I don't know where the problem is. I added the custom domain to the app setting of facebook developers page. But it's still showing that error message. If I turn off the redirection to 'www.tariquldipu.net' and just only keep 'tariquldipu.blogspot.com', then the comment box seems to work fine. But when I enable the custom domain it is showing the same problem again and again.
here is what object debugger is showing for the original URL('tariquldipu.blogspot.com')- 'https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=tariquldipu.blogspot.com'

and for the custom domain('www.tariquldipu.net')- 'https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=www.tariquldipu.net'

my app id for the comment box is- 199468180253830   and i've only one app id

here is what my app id page looks like- http: // i.stack.imgur.com/ZqPOU.png

I don't have much knowledge about web design/programming, maybe that's why i can't figure out the solution. but this problem is driving me crazy. Plaese me help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

On the App Domains field just put your URL without the 'www', like this, i.e **tariquldipu.net**
The change may take a moment to take effect.